# How to work with date/times in Swift when users are in different time zones?

Tags: swift

I have a number of blog posts with a publish date set at UTC time. I want to indicate the age of the post (1 hour, 1 day, 1 month, etc)  How do I detect the time zone of the user so I can properly convert UTC date/time?

Thanks!

Edit:

I'm using DateHelper Date Extension on GitHub:
https://github.com/melvitax/DateHelper

```
let sqlDate = post.age
        var hoursSincePost = sqlDate.hoursAfterDate(Date())
        hoursSincePost = abs(hoursSincePost)

       var daysSincePost = sqlDate.daysAfterDate(Date())
        daysSincePost = abs(daysSincePost)
        if hoursSincePost < 24 {
            age.text = String(hoursSincePost) + " hours ago"
        } else if daysSincePost < 7 {
            age.text = String(daysSincePost) + " days ago"
        } else {
            age.text =  sqlDate.toString(.custom("MMM dd yyyy"))
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the user's timezone? 
Surely the age of the post can be worked out based on the UTC time.  1 hour ago is 1 hour ago no matter where the user is.

Comment: Yes, because my app is currently showing every post as 5 hours from now. I'm in the Eastern Time Zone, 5 hours behind Greenwich Mean Time (London)

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you currently use to calculate the post's age.

Comment: Thanks @robmayoff.  Added code.

Comment: @Mark_1.  I totally got what you just said.  Duh.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Calendar](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/calendar) and [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter) to get the user's time zone or a specific time zone. If you don't know how to use them, here's [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)